# C udp recvfrom client side

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I'm writing udp server/client application in which server is sending data and client
is receiving. When packet is loss client should sent nack to server. I set the socket as
O_NONBLOCK so that I can notice if the client does not receive the packet

```
if (( bytes = recvfrom (....)) != -1 ) {
  do something
}else{
  send nack
}
```

My problem is that if server does not start to send packets client is behave as the
packet is lost and is starting to send nack to server. (recvfrom is fail when no data is available)I want some advice how can I make difference between those cases , if the server does not start to send the packets and if it sends, but the packet is really lost

Comment: Document the difference between "packet is lost" and "packet has not arrived yet", and implement it.

Comment: In both cases recvfrom returns -1 , so I'm not sure how to make a difference

Comment: You can hardly blame `recvfrom`, it cannot look into the future. Perhaps the packet will arrive, perhaps it will not. You should decide  when to stop waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using UDP. For this protocol its perfectly ok to throw away packets if there is need to do so. So it's not reliable in terms of "what is sent will arrive". What you have to do in your client is to check wether all packets you need arrived, and if not, talk politely to your server to resend those packets you did not receive. To implement this stuff is not that easy,

If you have to use UDP to transfer a largish chunk of data, then design a small application-level protocol that would handle possible packet loss and re-ordering (that's part of what TCP does for you). I would go with something like this:

Datagrams less then MTU (plus IP and UDP headers) in size (say 1024 bytes) to avoid IP fragmentation.
Fixed-length header for each datagram that includes data length and a sequence number, so you can stitch data back together, and detect missed, duplicate, and re-ordered parts.
Acknowledgements from the receiving side of what has been successfully received and put together.
Timeout and retransmission on the sending side when these acks don't come within appropriate time.

you have a loop calling either `select()` or `poll()` to determine if data has arrived - if so you then call recvfrom() to read the data.

you can set time out for receive data as follows

ssize_t
recv_timeout(int fd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
{

```
ssize_t ret;

struct timeval tv;
fd_set rset;

// init set
FD_ZERO(&rset);
// add to set
FD_SET(fd, &rset);

 // this is set to 60 seconds
tv.tv_sec =
    config.idletimeout;
tv.tv_usec = 0; 

    // NEVER returns before the timeout value.
ret = select(fd, &rset, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (ret == 0) {
    log_message(LOG_INFO,
                "Idle Timeout (after select)");
    return 0;
} else if (ret < 0) {
    log_message(LOG_ERR,
            "recv_timeout: select() error \"&#37;s\". Closing connection (fd:%d)",
            strerror(errno), fd);
    return;
} 

ret = recvfrom(fd, buf, len, flags);
return ret;
```

}

It tells that if there are data ready,  Normally, read() should return up to the maximum number of bytes that you've specified, which possibly includes zero bytes (this is actually a valid thing to happen!), but it should never block after previously having reported readiness.

> Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready
>   for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks. This could
>   for example happen when data has arrived but upon examination has
>   wrong checksum and is discarded. There may be other circumstances in
>   which a file descriptor is spuriously reported as ready. Thus it may
>   be safer to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block.

Comment: Dear JKB, I'm writing real time application, so I will delay sending for few seconds to have time to resend the lost packet's,....can I use non blocking socket instead of select or poll? What is the difference? Thx

Comment: @user3119422 you can use non-blocking socket with `select()`.Please see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

Look up sliding window protocol [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol).

The idea is that you divide your payload into packets that fit in a physical udp packet, then number them. You can visualize the buffers as a ring of slots, numbered sequentially in some fashion, e.g. clockwise.

Then you start sending from 12 oclock moving to 1,2,3... In the process, you may (or may not) receive ACK packets from the server that contain the slot number of a packet you sent.

If you receive a ACK, then you can remove that packet from the ring, and place the next unsent packet there which is not already in the ring.

If you receive a NAK for a packet you sent, it means that packet was received by the server with data corruptions, and then you resend it from the ring slot reported in the NAK.

This protocol class allows transmission over channels with data or packet loss (like RS232, UDP, etc). If your underlying data transmission protocol does not provide checksums, then you need to add a checksum for each ring packet you send, so the server can check its integrity, and report back to you.

ACK and NAK packets from the server can also be lost. To handle this, you need to associate a timer with each ring slot, and if you don't receive either a ACK or NAK for a slot when the timer reaches a timeout limit you set, then you retransmit the packet and reset the timer.

Finally, to detect fatal connection loss (i.e. server went down), you can establish a maximum timeout value for all your packets in the ring. To evaluate this, you just count how many consecutive timeouts you have for single slots. If this value exceeds the maximum you have set, then you can consider the connection lost.

Obviously, this protocol class requires dataset assembly on both sides based on packet numbers, since packets may not be sent or received in sequence. The 'ring' helps with this, since packets are removed only after successful transmission, and on the receiving side, only when the previous packet number has already been removed and appended to the growing dataset. However, this is only one strategy, there are others.

Hope this hepls.

Comment: Dear DNT, I'm not sure if this algorithm is too complicated and unefficient because my aplication will be in real time, and it must be really simple,I thought to use just nack to avoid congestion, but the main problem will be timers I will delay sending for few seconds to have time to resend lost packets and order them ...Also I don't know a lot of about ring buffer, I thought to use hash tables and to lookup packet by id from them

Comment: A ring buffer is just a circular list of data buffers. For example, a std::vector<your data buffer ref> mydata(number_of_buffers); Then you access it using n = (n+1) % number_of_buffers;  to handle it in a circular fashion. My description is only a summary of the sliding window, and it can be implemented relatively easily. Real time is also relative: since you need to ensure correct packet reception, you do need at the very least retransmission, timeouts and dataset assembly to avoid stop-and-wait situations.